# Wie kann man auf Deutsch sagen, dass man allein ist?

Tags: question

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen (single) und (ledig) auf Deutsch?

Comment: 1. Du sagst es nicht »dem Deutschen« (to one specific male person who is a citizen of the Federal Republic of Germany) sondern »auf Deutsch« (in German). Es gibt viele Deutsche, die nicht Deutsch sprechen (Menschen mit Migrationshintergrund, die deutsche Staatsbürger sind) und noch mehr Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache, die keine Deutschen sind (z.B. fast alle Österreicher) - 2. Entweder du verwendet zweimal *»man«* (»Wie sagt **man,** dass **man** allein ist?»)  oder zweimal *»ich«* (»Wie sage **ich,** dass **ich** allein bin?»). Ich habe in deiner Überschrift beide Fehler korrigiert.

Answer (score 6):

**Single** heißt, ich habe keinen Freund und keine Freundin im Sinne eines exklusiven Partners.

**Ledig** ist eher ein formaler Begriff und heißt: nicht verheiratet.

Answer (score 1):

In Ergänzung zu Olafants Anwort:

Hier ein paar Ausdrücke, mit denen man sagen kann, dass man keine feste Partnerin / keinen festen Partner hat:

> single,
> der Single,
> solo,
> alleinstehend,
> ohne festen Partner / ohne feste Partnerin,
> unbemannt / unbeweibt, *(ein Raumfahrt-Begriff, entsprechend alt ist der scherzhafte Gebrauch dieser Wörter)*
> noch zu haben

Der Ehe-Status wird offiziell mit diesen Wörtern angegeben:

> ledig (war nie und ist nicht verheiratet)
> verheiratet
> getrennt lebend
> geschieden
> verwitwet

"Ledig" bedeutet also nicht unbedingt, dass man single ist.

Answer (score 1):

- **ledig**
  Eine Person ist ledig, wenn sie unverheiratet ist und auch in der Vergangenheit noch nie verheiratet war. Jeder Mensch wird in diesem Zustand geboren. Sobald man heiratet ist man nicht mehr ledig sondern verheiratet. Die Ehe kann auf drei Arten enden:

  - Durch Scheidung. Danach ist man *geschieden* (so lange bis man wieder heiratet oder stirbt).
  - Durch den Tod des Ehepartners. Danach ist man *verwitwet* (so lange bis man wieder heiratet oder stirbt).
  - Durch den eigenen Tod. Danach ist man *tot* (und bleibt es für immer).
- **single**
  Für diesen Begriff gibt es keine allgemein anerkannte klare Definition. Für Statistiker ist eine Person "alleinstehend" (also single) wenn sie ohne andere Personen in einem Haushalt lebt. Personen, die mit einem Partner zusammenleben, aber auch Personen, die mit minderjährigen Kindern zusammenleben, gelten Statistikern nicht als "alleinstehend". Das deckt sich nicht ganz mit der Definition, die die meisten Menschen intuitiv verwenden. Denn für die meisten Menschen bedeuten *"in keiner Partnerschaft leben"* und *"single sein"* dasselbe. Demnach wären aber auch Kleinkinder single, daher ergänzen das viele Menschen noch um die Einschränkung, dass man entweder einen Partner sucht oder zumindest in einem Alter ist, in dem die Knüpfung einer neuen Partnerschaft üblich ist. Das heißt, dass Kinder meist nicht als *single* bezeichnet werden, und man auch bei alleinlebenden SeniorInnen eher zurückhaltend mit dieser Bezeichnung ist (Kaum jemand verwendet dieses Adjektiv für eine demente, bettlägerige 95-jährige Dame, die nie verheiratet war und ohne Angehörige in einem Hospiz ihre letzten Tage verbringt).
- **allein**
  Eine Person ist allein, wenn gerade niemand beim ihr ist. Das ist ein temporärer Zustand. Auch verheiratete Menschen oder Menschen, die in festen Partnerschaften leben sind allein, wenn sie ohne Begleitung z.B. Einkäufe im Supermarkt erledigen.

Answer (score -3):

Die Wörter bedeuten beide das selbe. Oft benutzt man "single" für jüngere und "ledig" für ältere Personen. "Ledig" ist auch förmlicher, in Dokumenten bei Behörden besteht z.B. oft die Auswahl aus "Ledig/Verheiratet/Verwitwet".

Edit: Ledig bedeutet streng genommen auch "Noch nie verheiratet". Nach einer Scheidung ist man also wieder single aber nicht ledig.

Comment: Dein letzter Satz widerspricht deinem ersten! Der erste Satz ist falsch, der letze ist richtig. In der Zeit in der ich verlobt war, war ich ledig (unverheiratet) aber nicht single (ohne Partner). Die beiden Wörter bedeuten daher **nicht** dasselbe!

Comment: Ledig bedeutet nicht nur strenggenommen "noch nie verheiratet", sondern immer.